# What is the example for difference between integration test and regression tests?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, regression-testing

Integration test checks that when units are combined, the systems fucntions well.

Regression tests also do the same. What is the example for difference between these?

Answer (score 0):

**Integration testing** - When combining units together that interact with each other you need to conduct Integration testing to make sure that integrating these units together has not introduced any errors.

**Regression testing** - after integrating (and maybe fixing) you should run your unit tests again. This is regression testing to ensure that further changes have not broken any units that were already tested. The unit testing you already did has produced the unit tests that can be run again and again for regression testing.

Comment: Not only Unit Test but application as a whole. Testing the Delta part(bug fixes) for the changes and other modules those were working fine previously.